# Encoding issue for French text

Tags: character-encoding

**My problem:** With my Emacs 26.1 on my 10.13.6 Mac, I have a opened a third-party text file, and it turns out I have the wrong encoding set : the text is in French , and the accentuated characters are displayed incorrectly (thus "é" is displayed as a brown `\216`, "î" as a brown `\224`, etc).

**What I tried :** I tried

`M-x revert-buffer-with-coding-system latin-1` and
`M-x revert-buffer-with-coding-system utf-8 emacs`
and nothing changed in the display.

I also tried (and failed) to guess the encoding : it must be an encoding in which "é" is the 216th character. Now é is U+00E9 in Unicode, which gives 233 in decimal. Also é is number 130 in extended ASCII.

Comment: That \216 is in octal => 142 decimal (but I have no clue which encoding it's using). It's not cp863 either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the [MacRoman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_Roman) encoding, a legacy encoding from the pre-OSX days of Mac OS. It is available in Emacs as `mac-roman`.

`C-x RET r mac-roman RET yes RET`

You may need to select `mac-roman-mac`, `mac-roman-dos` or `mac-roman-unix` explicitly if Emacs doesn't automatically detect the representation of line endings. The `mac-roman` part is for the encoding of non-ASCII characters.

If you want to specify the encoding of files with a certain extension, files in a certain directory, or more generally based on a file's path, you can call [`modify-coding-system-alist`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Recognize-Coding.html) in your init file, e.g. for all `*.txt` files that are in or under a directory called `old-mac-files`:

```
(modify-coding-system-alist 'file "/old-mac-files/.*\\.txt\\'" 'mac-roman-mac)
```

Comment: I just noticed that I have to re-execute this command every-time I re-open the file. Is there a command to put in init.el so that this particular file will always be opened with the correct encoding (leaving the others file alone) ?

Comment: @EwanDelanoy Yes, see my edit.

Comment: Thanks for your edit. I failed to implement it  correctly on my machine, and I've asked a new [question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/45219/unclear-error-messages-on-modify-coding-system-alist-command) about it.

Comment: @EwanDelanoy My bad, I forgot an argument to `modify-coding-system-alist`.

Comment: I understand that the dot needs to be escaped by a backslash before it, but what is the single quote at the end of the filename for ?

Comment: @EwanDelanoy `\'` in a regexp (`"\\'"` in a string literal since string literals need double-backslash for a single backslash in the resulting string) matches only at the end of the string. So this means: all file names that contain `/old-mac-files/`, followed by anything-except-a-newline (`.*`), followed by `.txt`. Without `\\'` it would also match e.g. `/old-mac-files/somedir.txt/somefile.binary`.